# Animation when changing 'home:' content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

```
class Segunda extends StatefulWidget {
  Tercera createState() => Tercera();
}

class Tercera extends State<Segunda> {
  var size, heightA, widthA;

  List<StatefulWidget> bodys = [Segunda2(), Segunda3()];

  int n = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      heightA = size.height;
      widthA = size.width;
    });

    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      width: widthA,
      height: heightA,
      child: Column(children: [
        Container(
          width: widthA,
          height: heightA * 0.1,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  n++;
                });
              },
              child: Text("Change")),
        ),
        Container(
          width: widthA,
          height: heightA * 0.9,
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: bodys[n],
          ),
        )
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

I want to always have a little bar at the beginning of my app, but changing the content (im learning flutter and i want to make a little game).

So, I made a test app like this

[image]

that changes the content when you press a button, I have a list with different StatefulWidgets (Segunda2 and Segunda3 returns just a solid background color).

Is there anyway I can add a animation when changing the content of the 'home', like the ones you can do with Navigator (the new content sliding from the left, for example)

Im using this way because when I try to use navigator to change between classes while trying to have a permanent widget (like the blue bar in this case) it just ignores it and changes the whole thing, I want to press a button and see the new content coming from a side.

i tried using navigator to change content with an animation, but the persistent widget that i want to have just changes as well.

I tried using persistent widget perse, and it didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple `MaterialApp` and you can use PageView widget.

Try to follow this widget structure:

```dart
void main() => runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Segunda(),
    );
  }
}

class Segunda extends StatefulWidget {
  Tercera createState() => Tercera();
}

class Tercera extends State<Segunda> {
  var size, heightA, widthA;

  // List<StatefulWidget> bodys = [Segunda2(), Segunda3()];
  List<Widget> bodys = [Text("Segunda2"), Text("Segunda3")];

  final PageController controller = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, constraints) {
        heightA = constraints.maxHeight;
        widthA = constraints.maxWidth;
        return Container(
          width: widthA,
          height: heightA,
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              width: widthA,
              height: heightA * 0.1,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // setState(() {});
//                     controller.animateToPage(page,
//                         duration: duration, curve: curve);
                    controller.nextPage(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.ease);
                  },
                  child: Text("Change")),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: controller,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return bodys[index];
                },
              ),
            )
          ]),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can I go to a specific page or I have to go next/previous page everytime?? My menu will have a few buttons and i want to be able to select where i want to go

Comment: the classes i want to use as pages are States, and that seems to crash everything a lot

Comment: Yes you can, check `animateToPage(page`  the comment section . try to remove top level widget from scaffold on `Segunda2`, & ...., Try to follow the posted snippet